# What is the meaning of target-confirmation?

Tags: json-rpc

The API call **listsinceblock** has an optional parameter called **target-confirmations**.  Exactly what does it mean and how does it differ from the **minconf** optional parameter that many other calls take?  I understand the use of **minconf**, but I cannot at first glance see what's different about **target-confirmations**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's pretty much the same thing.  It probably should have been called 'minconf'.